# Ideal settings for rdesktop?

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, rdesktop

For connecting to a Windows 7 virtual machine on a LAN, what would be the ideal settings to specify when using rdesktop in linux so that it feels as close as possible to using a regular Windows 7 machine? And is there anything I should configure on the Windows VM?

Answer (score 10):

It takes some tweaking. The command-line I'm using in a shortcut for my VMWare VM Win7 admin station is :

`/usr/local/bin/rdesktop -d $domain -u $username -g 1270x972 -z -r sound:local -P -x l $hostname`

Works pretty solidly. I had to compile a newer rdesktop since the one that comes with my distro is a bit old. Pretty snappy. Still not as snappy as talking to XP, but markedly better than it is with no special options.

Comment: the sound from remote machine is a bit choppy and laggy.

Comment: There is some discussion of `-P` (bitmap caching) at https://superuser.com/questions/6962/what-does-the-bitmap-caching-option-do-in-the-remote-desktop-client

Answer (score 4):

I came upon this after investigating various sources. Here's what I use:

```
rdesktop -u USERNAME -d DOMAINNAME -p - -g 1680x1050 -a 24 -z -x 0x80 -D -r clipboard:PRIMARYCLIPBOARD -r sound:remote MACHINENAME
```

`-x 0x80` will allow clear type tuning to work ([see here](http://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2008/03/10/rdesktop-connect-to-windows-vista-with-cleartype-font-smoothing-enabled/)) assuming you have Windows XP SP3, Vista or 7 as the server.

If you get a warning saying 24 bit color depth is not allowed, you will need to use the group policy edtor on the server machine to change the Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Terminal Services -> "Limit maximum color depth" setting. ([see here](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/789/))

I forgot to mention, on Windows XP, you will also need to add a DWORD value to your registry: `AllowFontAntiAlias` with value `1` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp` ([source](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/windows-cleartype-on-rdp/)) and restart your machine.

The above also removed windows manager decorations and passes all keys (Ctrl+Alt+Del etc.) to the Windows machine. I have the resolution explicitly specified in place of using full screen mode on rdesktop to prevent it from taking over both monitors.

Answer (score 3):

After some grief, I've switched to using `xfreerdp` - it lacks a lot of the issues rdesktop has with the more modern windows builds, and feels a bit faster (might be wrong here)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all the answers share something like these options in common:

- `-x lan`: Let rdesktop know you have a good connection
- `-P`: Let rdesktop cache bitmaps
- `-z`: Let rdesktop use compression

Answer (score 1):

I like to add the `-f` option instead of the `-g <dimensions>`, as it enables the Full Screen mode.

Then you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to toggle Full Screen.